# pipenv переменные окружения пропадают после перезагрузки

Tags: python, rest, flask, pipenv

Пытаюсь сделать приложение по этому туториалу 
https://www.codementor.io/olawalealadeusi896/restful-api-with-python-flask-framework-and-postgres-db-part-1-kbrwbygx5

и столкнулся с проблемой. 
Каждый раз при перезагрузке ПК приходится заново прописывать переменные окружения

```
$ export FLASK_ENV=development
$ export DATABASE_URL= postgres://name:password@houst:port/blog_api_db
$ export JWT_SECRET_KEY = hhgaghhgsdhdhdd
```

Как их сохранить кхм... на подольше?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если мы говорим про сохранить подольше, то можно либо добавить их в `/etc/profile`, чтобы применить ко всей системе, либо в `~/.profile`, чтобы только для конкретного пользователя:

```
$ export FLASK_ENV=development
$ export DATABASE_URL= postgres://name:password@houst:port/blog_api_db
$ export JWT_SECRET_KEY = hhgaghhgsdhdhdd
```

Однако это плохой паттерн разработки, ибо нельзя будет переиспользовать ваше решение на другом компьютере. Правильным будет использование виртуального окружения + инициализация этих переменных при деплое.